# Identifying each component on raspberry-pi3B+

Tags: pi-3b+

Can anyone help me to identify each and every component on pi, like where is wifi chip, which one is processor etc etc?

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is not open hardware. There's no bill of materials, there's no complete schematic. What are you hoping to get?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the community. I've found a diagram on the internet from The Engineering Projects.

[image: RPi 3 B+ Diagram]

Comment: I found another one: https://imgur.com/gallery/oWoaV9H.

Comment: And Rpi3B+ bottom polyfuse: https://imgur.com/9HTCE8V.

Comment: More components at the bottom of the Rpi3B+: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104596/rpi3b-micro-usb-connector-got-15v-power-is-it-dead-can-i-save-it/104614#104614.

Comment: The one at https://imgur.com/gallery/oWoaV9H shows the diagram of RPi 4B, but the question refers to RPi 3B+.

Comment: Thank you sir, for sharing....i need some more information like about the identification of each chips present on the board like which one is wifi chip, which one is processor...like this.

Comment: @Sukanya Pandey, thks for pointing out my careless mistake. My apologies. I was not aware the OP wants 3B+ only, 3A, 3B out of topic. I included 4B because the 3B+ diagram does not say about the black chip near the USB connector.  OP does not mention if components on the bottom side also needed. So I hope 3B+ bottom should not be out of topic. I included 4B becasuse Ithink  OP might upgrade to 4B sooner or later, so there is no harm knowing a little bit more about 4B. My apologies for any confusion caused. I am happy to remove my 4B diagram, if one more reader or the mod agrees with you.

Comment: I studied the components on both Rpi3 and Rpi4 in general, because many of the components used belong to the same family. For example both use the same power supply chip, poly fuses. and even shape and layout are more or less similar. etc, though new version of Rpi made improvements. I often found that weak, or easily damaged parts in old versions/releases are improved, so when repairing 3B for example, I compare 4B and 3B, I can guess from the differences that which 3B components are replaced in Rp4, so they might be the weak component I should check out first. Sorry for my long windedness.

Comment: Let us compare and contrast the power cct of both Rp3B and Rpi4B as a case study.  You can find the layout of the components of the PSU of Rpi4 in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103610/rpi4b-power-connector-smd-components-damaged-how-to-replace-it. You will find the component layouts of Rpi3 and Rpi 4 are very similar. My answer also includes a schematic of the power supply circuit, and how traced the components to guess which is inductor, capacitors etc, so to make repair easy.  I agree that I might be over doing a bit, but I think in general more info is better than less. :)

Comment: Yet one more picture of the bottom of Rpi PCB the OP might be interested: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/1200x900/3055-05.jpg. Often I look at the bottom of the PCB to guess what is up above, for curiosity and for easy repairing. You may find the big black chip at the bottom of old versions of Rpi is no long on new versions.  I guess this might mean many things, say they can now squeeze more components on top, therefore remove all bottom big chips up. Often you need to goggle around to find hackers discussing about components, and sometimes need to write to Rpi Foundation which do often reply.

Comment: @Sukanya Pandey, the top right chip with the Raspberry Pi logo is the wireless chip. The Broadcom cortex chip is the CPU processor.